# How to say “A person not to mess with" in French?

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

What is the French equivalent of the expression "A person not to mess with" in the sense provided below

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-teach-people-not-to-mess-with-you

I consider *redoutable*, *atroce*, *frayant*, *terrible*, *horrible* as single-word interpretations but I am wondering if there are other words or expressions more appropriate.

Does the sentence below have the same meaning?

> C'est une personne avec laquelle on (ne) joue pas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some informal sentences that would match "He is someone not to mess with":

> *(Il (ne)) **Faut pas le chercher***.
>
> *(Il (ne)) Faut pas déconner avec lui*.
>
> *(Il (ne)) Faut pas jouer au con avec lui*.

Comment: _Faut pas niaiser avec_. (Qc fam.). Merci !

Answer (score 3):

**quelqu'un à qui il ne faut pas se frotter** *ou* **quelqu'un à qui ne pas se frotter**

**quelqu'un avec qui ne pas plaisanter**

Answer (score 3):

Quelqu'un qu'on préfère ne pas rencontrer seul la nuit

Il vaut mieux changer de trottoir quand on le rencontre

Faut éviter  les  embrouilles avec lui

Plus gentil : qui s'y frotte s'y pique

Comment: +1 for [Qui s'y frotte s'y pique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qui_s'y_frotte_s'y_pique_(devise))